# Redhat Linux Network Interface Autostart

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, network-interface, virtual-network-interface

We have a PostgreSQL cluster with 2 instances, one of them primary and other one is primary. Both of them are running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa). In order unify connection string we use virtual IP.

We have problem with managing virtual IP. We are managing VIP manually.

On the standby node content of my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1 :

```
NAME="eth0:1"
DEVICE="eth0:1"
ONBOOT=no
NETBOOT=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=$My-VIP
NETMASK="255.255.255.240"
TYPE=Ethernet
PEERDNS=no
```

When I reboot this standby server it tries to start "eth0:1" interface even though "ONBOOT=no" parameter and that cause trouble because same VIP, "$My-VIP", is already taken by primary instance.

Is there any other configuration that I should check?

If you need extra information or logs please let me know I will provide it as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to news that I got from my ex colleagues it is because of base interface, "eth0". After reboot eth0 starts all interfaces that depends on it. Only way to get rid of this commenting IPADDR out for eth0:1.